# Regular expression for begins with and ends with

Tags: regex, git, terminal

I'm trying to run a search with git to get me all the staged files in one of two folders: local or components. I only want to get JS files. The command runs in the console.

What I have so far:

```
STAGED_FILES=($(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep "^(local|components).*?.js"))
```

This gets me all the staged files:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM
```

This gets me all files paths beginning with local or components

```
grep "^(local|components)"
```

And this gets me all js files

```
grep ".js"
```

And this returns me nothing for some reason:

```
($(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep "^(local|components).*?.js"))
```

What is the Regular Expression that I could search with that would get me all the js files in these two folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It didn't work because `grep` doesn't support `?` lazy matches. You can use `-E` for extended regular expressions.

For example consider these

```
$ echo "asfasdfzasdfasdfz" | grep -E "a.*?z"
asfasdfzasdfasdfz
$ echo "asfasdfzasdfasdfz" | grep  "a.*?z"
$ echo "asfasdfzasdfasdf?z" | grep  "a.*?z"
asfasdfzasdfasdf?z
```

As you can see without `-E` it tries to match `?` also within the string.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the regular expression based answers, you can do this directly in Git, which has the notion of a "pathspec" including shell style globbing:

```sh
git diff --cached --name-only \
    --diff-filter=ACM -- 'local/**/*.js' 'components/**/*.js'
```

(line broken for display formatting; note that the `**` support is new in Git version 1.8.2).

That said, regular expressions are "more powerful" than shell globs, so you may want to keep [nu11p01n73R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870545/1256452) in mind.  Note, however, that non-greedy matches (`*?`) match as *little* as possible, rather than as *much* as possible:

```
pattern       input      result (matched part in parentheses)

abc.*e     0abcdefeged        0(abcdefege)d
abc.*?e    0abcdefeged        0(abcde)feged
abc.*d     0abcdefeged        0(abcdefeged)
abc.*?d    0abcdefeged        0(abcd)efeged
```

Your expression, `^(local|components).*?.js`, says (in extended interpretations anyway): match the start of line; then match either `local` or `components` as literal text; then match as few characters as possible, perhaps none; then match any character; then match a literal `j`; then match a literal `s`.  Hence this matches `local-jaguar-xjs-vehicles` because it begins with `local`, contains some text, has one character more before `js`, and continues on.

The shell glob pattern `local/**/*.js` matches only the *directory* `local`, followed by any number—possibly zero—of subdirectory components, followed by a file whose name *ends with* `.js`, with the dot matched literally.  So this is equivalent to the pattern `^local/(.*/|)[^/]*\.js$`: the literal text `local` matched at the start of the line, followed by one slash; followed by either: any number of characters ending in slash (taking as many as possible), or nothing at all; followed by any number (including none) of any character except slash, followed by a literal `.js`, followed by the end of the line.

Note that because this expression is anchored at both ends (must match at the beginning *and* end of line), and there is only one [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) in the middle, it does not matter whether we use a greedy or non-greedy match: the left-side anchor matches at the left and the right-side anchor matches at the right, and a greedy match takes as much of the middle as it can—i.e., all of it—while a non-greedy match takes as *little* of the middle as it can ... which is *still* "all of it".

(This does, of course, assume that the file names are being printed with just one on each line.  Fortunately `git diff --name-only` does just that.  Also, shell `**` for "any number of directories" is not supported in all shells, nor all non-shell file name globbing, but it *is* used in Git's [pathspecs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) (search for "pathspec").)

Comment: This actually helps a lot. Thank you.